# I'm having trouble understanding SOLID principles

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I could really use some help with this one. I'm trying to use SOLID principles in my next php project but i'm having a really tough time understading it. First of all, i can't really grasp single responsibility principle.

Let's say i'm creating user registration. First, i will create Database class for connecting to database. Then, i will create Register class that will receive all the user input from form. I will create methods in Register class that will check the input and clean it. And now comes the hard part. Let's say i want to check if email already exist. I also need to check if username already exist. To do that, i need access to the database. So, i can pass my db connection to Register object. But, it seems to me that, if i follow SOLID principles, i shouldn't touch database in my Register class methods. I can't really understand why is it bad doing it that way?

I can create some DbHandler class that will handle queries, binding parameters and executing queries, and pass the information from Register object to it and then check if username and email already exist. But that, to me, looks unnecessary. And, for the Register class, there will be very few things to do.

Would it be good solution to create, let's say, some RegisterDB class, that will handle db interactions for Register object? But again, Register class would be doing just a few thing.

My head will explode, i could really use help with this, guys.

Comment: Read about MVC architecture and repository pattern, that should help you.

Comment: Design your classes for one layer at a time, starting with the frontmost. Only move to the next layer when you are satisfied with all classes in the current layer. This way, you avoid overloading classes with too many responsibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You should read some literature about software design and design principles, it seems that you lack some major points of them.
First of all, following SOLID is a good approach, but you should go further and think in abstartions.
To your specific problem: you should create a interface or abstract class to represent your database handling, and then implement a specific database handler in a sperate subclass or implement the interface in this class. THis will contribute to Liskov's substitue principle and the interface segregation principle. With this approach, you can use the abstraction of the database handler outside and you don't have to care wether it is a MariaDB, an OrcaleDB or whatever, because you don' work on the specific class.
To your verification problem: since this is a general problem it also belongs to your abstraction, because every database handler needs to check wether a user already exists or not, so feel free to implement a method that takes a username and returns a boolean if this one already exists.
This whole approach will satisfy the Dependency inversion principle which will increase maintainability of your code and will make it much more clean to read and easier to extend, because you can switch the concrete implementations  any time without touching the code that uses them.
Here is some literature to these topics:
https://stackify.com/dependency-inversion-principle/